# iOS - Autolayout - Increase/Decrease view size proportionally on orientation change

Tags: ios, xcode6, autolayout

I went through ray wenderlich's tutorial about autolayouts ([link](http://www.raywenderlich.com/83130/beginning-auto-layout-tutorial-swift-part-2)) and then began working on a demo project thinking I've figured it all out but I was wrong. As shown in the screenshot below I have a navigation bar, 2 views and 1 button. The layout on portrait mode looks fine without adding any constraints on views or the button, and understandably in landscape mode views are messed up. I tried adding following constraints on views and those don't seems to work.

- View#2: Select view 2 > Editor > Align > Horizontal center in container (hides view completely)

[image]

- Add Top space to superview. Again view goes away from both landscape and portrait preview.

[image]

- If I can display view#2 correctly I am planning to add vertical space between view#2 & view#3 and then between view#3 and button#4.

My main concern is to resize the views so that it shows all views and buttons in iPhone 4s landscape mode. Any advise or suggestions are appreciated.

EDIT: Here's the end result that I am trying to get:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason your views go away when you add constraints is because a UIView has no intrinsic content size, so its size is {0,0}. The view appeared when you didn't add constraints because the system adds constraints for you, if you don't add them yourself; the system added ones are top, left, width, and height. So, you need to set the size of the views somehow. You can give them explicit size constraints, you can pin them to the edges of the superview, you can give them relative heights based on other views, etc.

Since you want the 2 views to get proportionally smaller in landscape, you should give them heights that are relative to the superview. You do this by selecting the view and the superview, and choosing "Equal Heights" from the pin menu. Edit that constraint to change the multiplier to something like 0.25 for the blue view and 0.2 for the orange one (this assumes that orange or blue view are the first item in the constraint -- if they are the second, then you should use the inverse values of 4 and 5). You should also do the same for the widths, since it seems you want them to get proportionally smaller too.

Comment: 2 and 3 should be proportionally shorter. I want to achieve something like this. https://www.dropbox.com/s/7if9a22sra28eud/Screenshot%202015-06-05%2014.30.31.png?dl=0

Comment: Thanks @rdelmar. I cant select the superview. am i missing something?

Comment: @Zhr select your subview, hold down the "command" key, and then click on the controller's main view in the scene list (instead of on the canvas).

Comment: Thanks but I had already tried it. the "Equal heights" option is disabled in that case. https://www.dropbox.com/s/whw8swqm90221c3/Screenshot%202015-06-05%2017.24.02.png?dl=0

Comment: @Zhr yeah, that's because your view is in the navigation bar, so I guess you can't do that. Are your blue and orange views supposed to be in the navigation bar?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79824/discussion-between-rdelmar-and-zhr).